# Python multiprocessing for dummies

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to find a simple example that clearly shows a single task being divided for multi-processing.

Quite frankly, many of the examples are overly sophisticated thus making the flow tougher to play with.

Does anyone care to share their breakthrough sample or an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic example is this:

```
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> worker_pool = mp.Pool()
>>> jobs = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25] 
>>>
>>> # calculate jobs in blocking batch parallel
>>> results = worker_pool.map(sqrt, jobs)
>>> results
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
>>>
>>> # calculate jobs in asynchronous parallel
>>> results = worker_pool.map_async(sqrt, jobs)
>>> results.get()
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
>>>
>>> # calculate jobs in parallel with an unordered iterator
>>> results = worker_pool.imap_unordered(sqrt, jobs)
>>> list(results)  # NOTE: results may return out of order
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
>>>
>>> # a single blocking job on another process
>>> worker_pool.apply(sqrt, [9])
3.0
>>> # a single asynchronous job on another process
>>> y = worker_pool.apply_async(sqrt, [9])
>>> y.get()
3.0
>>> # the same interface exists for threads
>>> thread_pool = mp.dummy.Pool()
>>> thread_pool.map(sqrt, jobs)
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
>>>
>>> # finishing up, you should shut down your pools
>>> worker_pool.close()
>>> worker_pool.join()
>>> thread_pool.close()
>>> thread_pool.join()
```

Examples can get more complex if you don't want batch parallel, but want something more complicated.